# Unix epoch in milliseconds

Tags: bash, shell-script, date, timestamps, time

I'm prepending the Unix epoch with "nanosecond" precision into output of my command as below:

```
$ command | while read line; do d=`date +%s%N`; echo $d $line; done > file
```

I looked around to find out how to turn "nanosecond" into "millisecond". For example, I followed the solution given [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/151109/how-do-i-get-current-unix-time-in-milliseconds-using-bash). So, I tried both suggested approaches:

```
$ command | while read line; do d=`echo $(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))`; echo $d $line; done > file
$ command | while read line; do d=`date +%s%N | cut -b1-13`; echo $d $line; done > file
```

However, in both cases when I insert the file into InfluxDB and query my database I get this:

```
time    
1970-01-01T00:24:05.419982325Z  
1970-01-01T00:24:05.419982344Z  
1970-01-01T00:24:05.419982371Z  
1970-01-01T00:24:05.419982378Z  
1970-01-01T00:24:05.419982388Z  
1970-01-01T00:24:05.419982401Z
```

**Update**

When I use epoch with nanosecond accuracy `date +%s%N`, I get this:

```
time
2015-10-21T08:59:59.978902683Z  
2015-10-21T08:59:59.982615836Z  
2015-10-21T08:59:59.983958069Z  
2015-10-21T08:59:59.98805317Z   
2015-10-21T08:59:59.99717678Z   
2015-10-21T09:00:00.028624495Z
```

I'm expecting such an output:

```
2015-10-21T09:12:10.001327Z
```

Please let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: What output do you actually want? Milliseconds since the epoch? Please [edit] your question and show us an example of the correct output.

Comment: you could try adding an explicit `u` suffix to the number so it is recognised by InfluxDB as an absolute time, eg `echo ${d}u $line`.

Comment: The epoch is 0. By definition. It doesn't really matter whether that's ns, ms, or any other measure - it's still zero. So presumably you're trying to do something other than "prepending the Unix epoch with "nanosecond" precision". Please can you clarify what you are really trying to do.

Comment: @terdon I intend to add epoch with millisecond accuracy to each line of my output file. For nanoseconds it works perfectly fine with Influxdb but when I use millisecond epoch the Influxdb assumes all 0 (1970-01-01T00:24:05.419982325Z).

Comment: Again, please *[edit]* your question and show us your desired output.

Comment: @roaima The output file with nanosecond epoch works fine in Influxdb. But I later I'm doing some calculations on timestamps so that why I'm trying to avoid timestamp with high accuracy like nanoseconds.

Comment: Epoch means "start of time". Which is zero by definition. What do you mean when you use the word "epoch"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `bc` and `printf`:

```
printf "%0.f" "$(bc <<<"$(date +"%s.%N")*1000")"
```

This gives the number of miliseconds since january 1970. I didn't use the `scale=n` option of `bc` on purpose, because that would not round the value, instead it cuts the rest away (I know, it's pedantic). bc reads from file or from the standard input. `<<<` is a [here string](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) which expands the contents and supplies them as standard input to `bc`. This is given to `printf` to round the value.

---

See this as an example:

```
$ d=$(date "+%s.%N")
$ echo $d; bc <<<"scale=0; ($d*1000)/1"; printf "%0.f" "$(bc <<<"$d*1000")"
1445423229.512731661 # plain date
1445423229512 # bc with scale
1445423229513 # bc/printf
```

---

In the loop it would then look like this:

```
command | while read line; do
  d=$(printf "%0.f" "$(bc <<<"$(date +"%s.%N")*1000")")
  echo "$d $line"
done >file
```

Answer (score 3):

nano is 10<sup>−9</sup> and milli 10<sup>−3</sup>. Hence, we can use the 3 first characters of nanoseconds to get the milli:

```
date +%s%3N
```

From `man date`:

> **%N**     nanoseconds (000000000..999999999)
>
> **%s**     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

Source: Server Fault's [How do I get current Unix time in milliseconds using bash?](https://serverfault.com/a/588705/200076). Note I posted this same answer in Stack Overflow's equal question [Linux command to get time in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31020758).

Answer (score 2):

You nearly had it right, just a couple of back ticks too many

```
$ d=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
$ echo $d
1445422618527
$ d=$(date +%s%N)
$ echo $d $(( d / 10 )) $(( d / 1000000 ))
1445422673712321597 144542267371232159 1445422673712
```